# Log4j2: TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy strategy max not works

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, log4j2

"appender.file-log.strategy" isn't working well. My folder contains over 30 files. Do you have any suggestions? I'd like a maximum of 20 files.
Log4j2 version: 2.12.1

This is my code:

```
appender.file-log.type=RollingFile
appender.file-log.name=FileLog
appender.file-log.fileName=logs/myfolder/daily.log
appender.file-log.filePattern=logs/myfolder/daily.log.%d{yyyyMMdd}.%i.gz
appender.file-log.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file-log.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
appender.file-log.policies.type=Policies
appender.file-log.policies.date.type=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.file-log.policies.date.interval=1
appender.file-log.strategy.type=DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.file-log.strategy.max=20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with this solution and it seems to work well. I deleted the property

```
appender.file-log.strategy.max=20
```

and I replaced it with this code (after the appender.filelog.strategy.type):

```
appender.file-log.strategy.type=DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.file-log.strategy.delete.type=Delete
appender.file-log.strategy.delete.basePath=logs/myFolder/
appender.file-log.strategy.delete.maxDepth=1
appender.file-log.strategy.delete.ifAccumulatedFileCount.type=IfAccumulatedFileCount
appender.file-log.strategy.delete.ifAccumulatedFileCount.exceeds=20
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. The "max" parameter indicates what the maximum number of files should be during an interval. Once the max is reached older files during that interval are deleted. The DeleteAction, on the other hand, can delete anything.

Answer (score 0):

configuration looks correct to me, what I may suggest is to check whether permissions to delete files are set correctly and try to do some testing with a clean folder, so with no pre-existing files in place